# Build Vue.js in production serve

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I want to build the default template of Vue.js

`vue init webpack`

with this command
`node build/build.js`

Instead of having the same page that I have when running `npm run dev` I have a blank page.

Also I run `npm run build`

How to convert this site into a non-develop website ?

Vue version 2.9.6

Node version v8.15.1

Comment: The `build` task creates all the static HTML, CSS and JS required to run your site and dumps them in the `dist` directory. You can upload these to an HTTP server. See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Comment: You can check Vue

Comment: @Phill

I build again with npm run build and I put it on my /var/www/html and it doens't display anything I checked the developer console in Google Chrome and I see that the route of the css and javascript files are misspelled, /static/js/JSFILE.js instead of static/js/JSFILE.js. Why this happens?